# pasing parameter to ng-click function within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using `onclick="window.open('tel:+94777122240')"` in my angular ionic application. which lets the user to open dial box when onclick. i am trying to pass values to the `onclick` function withing `ng-repeat`. but the `ng-repeat` values doesnt pass to fucntion

i have used this method to solve it. but it does not work

```
<div ng-repeat="branch in branches"> 
<a ng-click="window.open('tel:branch.telephone')" class="button">Call Now</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to use the dialler to make a phone call?

Answer (score 1):

Angular expressions are evaluated against the scope.
Try to move the `ng-click` function to the controller:

```
$scope.open = function(branch) {
    window.open('tel:' + branch.telephone);
}

<div ng-repeat="branch in branches"> 
<a ng-click="open(branch)" class="button">Call Now</a>
</div>
```